# Microsoft Azure - How to export and create deployment script for Api Management

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

In Microsoft Azure, under API Management,
How to export Api with policy and frontend header/request paramters.
And create deployment script to deploy different environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use Git integration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git. It will allow you to export whole APIM configuration into Git repository.
2. Use ARM templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template. IT will require some celanup after initial export though.

Comment: When I export my API Management setting into an ARM template it does not contain any of the actual Endpoint mappings. No policies, frontend stuff

Comment: @Jepzen do you export an API item or the ARM template for the whole API Management Service instance?